# Localize shortcut menu in installshield

Tags: installshield-2011

I have shortcut Program menu -->Company Name --> Product name.
My requirement is the product name should be localized when locale language (operating system) is Japanese.
How is this possible in Install shield 2011?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer only supports localizing shortcut names in two ways. One is via language transform, which would then reflect the language chosen during installation as the sole name of a shortcut; this works with all versions of Windows Installer, but is only available in the Premier editions of InstallShield.

The other is through MUI properties. By setting the Display Resource setting of a shortcut to reference a multi-lingual resource dll, the name is updated to match the user's preferred language. This approach only works on machines with Windows installer 4.0 or later.